# Looking for a way to get Active Directory user accounts with logons less than 90 days

Tags: powershell

So far I tried this**
Does not seem to work well, I get dates back from 2014.
And only a few from 2022

```
$90Days = (get-date).adddays(-90)
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Domain Users,DC=x,DC=state,DC=x,DC=x" -properties * -filter {(lastlogondate -notlike "*" -OR lastlogondate -le $90days) -AND (passwordlastset -le $90days)} | select-object name, SAMaccountname, lastlogondate | export-csv c:\Temp\90days.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple flip from less than to greater than. Dates are stored as numbers that increment every millisecond. Starting at a date 90 days ago and asking for "less than" means get everything from 90 days ago and earlier, not 90 days and greater to "today".

Simply flip your `-le` to `-ge`.

```
$90Days = (get-date).adddays(-90)
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Domain Users,DC=x,DC=state,DC=x,DC=x" -properties * -filter {(lastlogondate -notlike "*" -OR lastlogondate -ge $90days) -AND (passwordlastset -ge $90days)} | select-object name, SAMaccountname, lastlogondate | export-csv c:\Temp\90days.csv
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! It's better, but I don't see users I know have logged on like myself co -workers that are admins, does this just check for users in OU =Domain Users, and not sub folders? Also I see users I've created today and some others that I know have not logged in because I just created today. Does not show logon time though, kind of puzzled by this!

Comment: I thinks I have to get clarification on what's needed, because the request was for All Active Directory users with accounts with logons less than 90 days, and I'm seeing this is getting users that have not logged in in 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is wrong. `lastlogondate -notlike "*" -OR` literally means *if LastLogonDate not like anything OR ..*.
This means it would almost always pass the test.

Then, I don't see why you also include property `PasswordLastset` in the equation as your question is not about that.

I think this would work better for you:

```
$90Days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90).Date  # set the date to midnight 

# to filter on enabled users only, you can also use the LDAPFilter parameter like:
# -LDAPFilter "(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq $true" -SearchBase "OU=Domain Users,DC=x,DC=state,DC=x,DC=x" -Properties LastLogonDate | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -ge $90Days} |
    Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate | 
    Export-CSV -Path 'c:\Temp\90days.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. Don't ask for **ALL** properties with `-Properties *` if you only want one extra property on top of the attributes returned by default like Name and SamAccountName.

Note: Please also bear in mind that the *calculated* property LastLogonDate (not really an AD attribute at all) is **not** replicated within the domain and to get the most accurate value, you need to iterate the domaincontrollers in your domain.

Comment: getting this  of error when running,

Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Enabled -eq True -and LastLogonDate -ge 03/05/2022 00:00:00' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '13'.
At line:3 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Domain Users,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @saxman88 Ah, please see my edited answer. Because `LastLogonDate` is not really an AD attribute at all, but instead a calculated property, it is better not to use that in a Filter but use a secondary Where-Object clause afterwards.